# Установка ffmpeg на Cent OS 7

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

Приветствую.
В общем возникла необходимость установить ffmpeg и php ffmpeg на сервер с Cent OS 7. Данный мануал https://my.9xhost.net/knowledgebase/article/39/install-ffmpeg---php-ffmpeg-on-centos-7-1/ не помог. Ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Странный мануал: в заголовке 7.1, а rpm для 6. Попробуйте этот: https://www.webfoobar.com/node/17 или этот: https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/MultimediaOnCentOS7

Или соберите сами. Ничего сложного в этом нет.

Comment: Сам я в серверах не очень разбираюсь, а сис.админ не справился с данной задачей.
Спасибо, гляну.

Comment: Попробовал сам установить. И не смог. FFMPEG как не работал так и не работает.

Comment: А можно уточнить: что именно не работает? На каком этапе возникает затык? Какой вывод на экран и так далее.

Comment: FFMPEG вроде как установлен http://joxi.ru/n2YOeQVijnJpOr


if (class_exists('ffmpeg_movie')){
    echo 'ok';
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
if(exec('ffmpeg'))
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'error';

Выдаёт error.

Comment: По вашей ссылке раздел "Install php-ffmpeg extension:" и внимательно смотреть на то, что видит или не видит PHP. Только учесть, что php.ini, скорее всего смотрится где-то в /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini